# Как последовательно запустить функции (дождаться выполнения первой, потом запустить следующую и так по порядку) на SWIFT?

Tags: многопоточность, swift, очередь, очередь-задач

Можете подсказать, как решить задачу:
Нужно запустить 4 функции (В функциях используется двойное замыкание.) по порядку, дождаться выполнения первой, потом запустить вторую и так далее.
Все функции с замыканиями и получают данные из интернета, время выполнения от 0.5 до 4 секунд?
Пробовал вот так (код упрощен, убраны проверки и тд):

```
let izolQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "plll", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
izolQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
   myfunc()
}
izolQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
   myfunc2()
}
izolQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
   myfunc2()
}
izolQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            myfunc2()
        }
```

но так не работает...

В чем проблема или какое решение нужно использовать?

Answer (score 1):

То что вам нужно - называется синхронным(последовательным) выполнением, а вы используете асинхронное выполнение. В вашем случае необходимо использовать `sync`. Так как не известно, что происходит у вас в функциях, я приведу свой пример.

```
func printMessage(with delay: UInt32, text: String) {
    sleep(delay)
    print("Ended - \(text)")
}

let meQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "test")

meQueue.sync {
    printMessage(with: 5, text: "1")
}
meQueue.sync {
    printMessage(with: 4, text: "2")
}
meQueue.sync {
    printMessage(with: 3, text: "3")
}
```

Вывод:

```
Ended - 1
Ended - 2
Ended - 3
```

Comment: В функциях используется двойное замыкание.

Comment: Так этот ваш код и без meQueue.sync {} будет работать так же. Если просто printMessage(with: text:) написать одно под другим.